# How can I get a fully functional FittedModel when fitting data to a pointwise function?

Tags: fitting

When I am fitting data with a pointwise function using `NonlinearModelFit`, the produced `FittedModel` fails to calculate variances and errors. Consider a toy example:

```
Clear[f, data];
data = {{1, 7.4}, {2, 1.9}, {3, 6.}};
f[1.] = 2. a + b;
f[2.] = 3. a/b;
f[3.] = 3. b/a + a;    
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[t], {a, b}, t, Method -> NMinimize]
```

When I take

```
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

it gives a correct result `{a -> 2.19044, b -> 2.95013}`. However, when I try to take

```
fit["EstimatedVariance"]
```

it throws exception, since values of `a` and `b` can not be substituted in `fit["Function"]` (that's my guess).

I found the following obvious workaround:

```
Clear[f, g, h];
f[1.] = 1; g[1.] = 0; h[1.] = 0;
f[2.] = 0; g[2.] = 1; h[2.] = 0;
f[3.] = 0; g[3.] = 0; h[3.] = 1;
fit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, (2 a + b) f[t] + 3 a/b g[t] + (3 b /a + a) h[t],
    {a, b}, t, Method -> NMinimize]
```

but it is not elegant at all.

What is the best way to obtain a complete `FittedModel` using `NonlinearModelFit` with a pointwise functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redefine the function:

```
Clear[f, data];
data = {{1, 7.4}, {2, 1.9}, {3, 6.}};
f[1., a_, b_] := 2. a + b;
f[2., a_, b_] := 3. a/b;
f[3., a_, b_] := 3. b/a + a;
```

Now it does what you want:

```
In[]:=  fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[t, a, b], {a, b}, t, Method -> NMinimize]
Out[]:= FittedModel[f[t,2.1904, 2.95013]]
In[]:=  fit["EstimatedVariance"]
Out[]:= 0.165311
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be overly complicating this problem. Here's a way to find the a and b that minimize your three equations:

```
FindMinimum[(7.4 - (2. a + b))^2 + (1.9 - (3. a/b))^2 + (6. - (3. b/a + a))^2, {a, b}]
```

which gives `{0.165311, {a -> 2.19044, b -> 2.95013}}`

So now you know the `a` and `b` that best fit the data, you can calculate whatever statistics you want from them. In particular, the first term (the error `0.165311`) is a measure of how good the functions with the given parameters fit the data. Since I used the squared error, this is much like the variance of the fit.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing in this way, but I tried to find a way to generate all statistics automatically using `NonlinearModelFit`.